# Is it possible for two ChromeApp WebViews to have different set of cookies?

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension, webview, google-chrome-app

I have a **chrome packaged app**, in which I use `WebView`s to open external content.

What I would like to achieve is to be able to log in with two different users in a webapp (that uses cookies for storing sessionID).

The problem is that the two `WebView`s seem to share the cookies among themselves.

I've searched through the documentation and internet but couldn't find any clues on how to separate cookie-spaces, or if that is even possible?

My guess would be it is not possible, since chrome itself can only run two sessions in parallel (normal & incognito), but I would really be interested to know it for sure, + maybe the reasons behind it.

Comment: Have you tried using [`partition` attribute](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#partition) for `<webview>`? I haven't worked with it myself, but it sounds relevant to what you try to achieve.

Comment: As it turns out I was not reading carefully enough. Yes that indeed worked. Thank you. If you care to copy your comment to an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I will a bit later. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<webview>` element has an [attribute `partition`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#partition) that achieves exactly what is required: you can have separate local browser states, persistent or not, possibly shared between several instances.